# Drawing connecting lines between points to nearest within layer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, arcgis-10.5, proximity, points-to-line

I need to connect points within one layer to the nearest with polyline. [image]Tool to the nearest would be ideal, but there is nothing in the attribute table.

[image]

I tried to find tool in X Y coordinate, but nothing works. It requires another attribute to run it to. Layer ID is not in any order. Tried XY tool. Tried [Creating best fit line from point data using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164523/creating-best-fit-line-from-point-data-using-arcgis-for-desktop)

[image]

Only connects some, and not always to the nearest.

None seem to work.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: May I ask what is your real goal?

Comment: This is a vector map of kurgans (1789–1865) map. Statistical analysis "to the nearest" shows mathematical dependencies roads, rivers, and kurgans. Ancient burial mounds served as road markers.  I need not to perform statistical analysis of distances, archeology, road network in attempt to recreate road network in historic period of interest.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/nQoKEI35HnbYIw

Answer (score 2):

Run generate NEAR on itself, add 4 fields to that table. Transfer from coordinates, using IN_FID:

[image]

Repeat for "to" coordinates, using NEAR_FID. Use XY to line, with IN_FID as ID:

[image]

Note: you'll have lines sharing ends running in opposite directions.

Comment: Almost working. Does not connect all of it, but better. For some reason cannot add picture.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/nQoKEI35HnbYIw

Comment: Ancient burial mounds served as road markers. I need to perform statistical analysis of distances, archeology, road network in attempt to recreate road network in historic period of interest

Comment: Another reason: you might have duplicate points or pairs sitting very close. Delete duplicating shapes maybe.

Comment: What you really need is minimum spanning tree of your points, not bits and pieces all over the he place.

Comment: I am not sure if I am adding fields right. May be just too tired. Can you show step by step how you see it done. Minimum Spanning tree is great suggestion. Thank you. Looking into it.